# C structure containing references to another structure

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, queue

I'm learning C and trying to create dynamic double ended queue. I need to have one structure element that contains references to queue's front and end (head, tail of type node) and I'm trying to pass this element to a function and allocate memory for head and tail node. And i get segmentation fault.

My structures

```
struct node_st {
    struct node_st* prev_node;
    struct node_st* next_node;

    // Value type can be changed.
    int value;

    bool is_zero_element;
};

typedef struct node_st node;

struct deque_link {
  struct node_st* head;
  struct node_st* tail;
  int errorcode;
};

typedef struct deque_link dlink;
```

Main function

```
#include "deque.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    dlink* deque;
    deque_create(deque);
}
```

deque_create() function

```
void deque_create(dlink* deque) {
  deque->head = deque->tail = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

}
```

I guess I don't understand pointers enough, but I will be very happy if someone could help.

Comment: Try to compile like "gcc -W -Wall -Werror -Wextra *.c" fix your compilation warnings and tell me if it works better or if you still have the problem

Comment: That did not work, but solution displayed in the answers worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer `deque` that you pass to `deque_create` is not initialized. It has indeterminate ("garbage") content. Therefore, it does not point to a valid deque. But you try to access it with the `->` operator.

Your initialization / creation of the deque is on the wrong level: You try to create nodes, but you should create a deque (without any nodes, initally.)

You could write a constructor function that allocates memory and initializes it:

```
dlink *deque_create(void)
{
    dlink *deque = malloc(sizeof(*deque));

    // Handle allocation failure

    deque->head = deque->tail = NULL;
    deque->errorcode = 0;

    return deque;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
dlink* deque = deque_create();

// do stuff with deque
// delete deque and its nodes
```

You should also write a destructor function which deletes all nodes to complement the constructor.